# How to exclude directories from phpunit coverage report

Tags: phpunit

I tried the following configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit>
    <testsuites>
      <testsuite name="My Test Suite">
         <directory suffix=".php">Test/Case/Model</directory>
        <exclude>Test/Case/Model/Behavior</exclude>
      </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

but it does not exclude the behaviour from coverage report. How to exclude these directories or files from the coverage report?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Refer to [the `exclude` element phpunit documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html#the-exclude-element).

Here is an example `phpunit.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phpunit>
  <filter>
    <whitelist>
      <directory suffix=".php">../</directory>
      <exclude>
        <file>../ext_emconf.php</file>
        <directory suffix=".php">../tests</directory>
      </exclude>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: About your age, is that a typo by any chance?  ;)

Comment: I always tell random sites in the internet my real birthdate.

Comment: SO calculated my age as 13

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is not longer accurate as it looks like the <filter> element has been removed from PHPUnit.

Comment: this has since been replaced as @risingfish mentioned. For phpunit 9.6:

https://docs.phpunit.de/en/9.6/configuration.html#the-exclude-element

`<exclude>
    <directory suffix=".php">src/generated</directory>
    <file>src/autoload.php</file>
</exclude>`